# How to make the Draggable element to get visible on top of all the element in the screen while dragging?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, sapui5

I need to to implement the **drag and drop feature in SAPUI5 Table and Tree Table**.

I have a **table** with a set of names which a user should be able to **drag** and a **Tree Table** which should accept the dragging object, so it is defined as a **drop** area.

I used JqueryUI to make the controls as drag and drop, which is working fine.

[image]

[image]

[image]

The problem is when I drag the name towards the Tree Table it is getting hidden behind the table which makes the user confused.

When I go through the code, I found out that this issue occurs due to the **position** related to CSS, which is applied default in SAPUI5.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Code for drag and drop:

```
var oMemberId;
$(".selector Table").draggable({
        helper: "clone",
        cursor: "pointer",
        revert: "invalid",  
        zIndex: 9999,
        start: function(event) {
            oSelectedId = this.parentNode.previousSibling.firstChild.childNodes[0].value;
                }
}).disableSelection();           

$(".selector treetable").droppable({ 
    drop: function(event){
        var dataLevel=(this.attributes["data-sap-ui-level"].value);
        var oDropAreaId = this.childNodes[2].textContent;
    }
}).disableSelection();
```

How can I prevent the dragged item from hiding?

Comment: Can you provide your drag and drop code? If I'm not mistaken you can provide a z-index there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var oMemberId;
$(".selector Table").draggable({
    helper: "clone",
    cursor: "pointer",
    revert: "invalid",

    zIndex: 9999,
    containment:"window",
    start: function(event, ui) {
        oMemberId = this.parentNode.previousSibling.firstChild.childNodes[0].value;
    },
    drag:function(event, ui) {
        $(".selector div.sapUiTableCnt,.selector div.sapUiTableCtrlScr").css("overflow","visible");
                }
            }).disableSelection();`

I am over writing the css on drag.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the dragged item gets set the class "ui-draggable-dragging"  (check by yourself in the console).

So, you just need to alter the z-index in css:

```
.ui-draggable-dragging {
    z-index:99999;
}
```

Comment: its not working. But got the result. Please see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Manipulate the z-index CSS property on `dragstart` of the dragged object for during the drag and then put it back afterwards.

Javascript:

```
$( ".selector" ).on( "dragstart", function( event, ui ) {
    $(ui.helper).css('z-index', '100000');
} );

$( ".selector" ).on( "dragstop", function( event, ui ) {
    $(ui.helper).css('z-index', '1');
} );
```

Comment: its not working. But got the result. Please see my answer below